# What was the rationale behind TEXT mode for FTP protocol design?

Tags: ftp, protocols, history, network-protocols

FTP has modes known as text and binary. For correct binary file transfers, some old-looking command line ftp clients seem to rely on the user to first switch the mode to `image` aka `binary` mode.

But this way text mode is also a potential way to screw up files. History may aid to shred a light on this choice. What is the history for providing the text mode in FTP and letting choose defaults?

Answer (score 0):

To allow users to transfer files between machines that use different line endings seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Without sources or first-hand knowledge, I speculate that the dominant use case for file transfers at the time was text files between machines with disparate encodings (ASCII vs EBCDIC; different line ending conventions).